# How to enforce a java compiler version with gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, javac

In all of my projects, I use gradle and specify the following:

```
sourceCompatibility = "1.7"; // for example
targetCompatibility = "1.7"; // defaults to sourceCompatibility
```

Now, I have three different versions of the JDK installed, from 1.6 to 1.8. In order to switch from one version to another, I `source` shell files to change `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` and even `JDK_HOME`.

By accident it can happen that I use the wrong JDK version and I don't want that... Is there a possibility to check that the compiler version is equal to targetCompatibility before attempting any compilation task?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use the following:

```
task checkJavaVersion << {
    if (!JavaVersion.current().isJava6()) {
        String message = "ERROR: Java 1.6 required but " +
                          JavaVersion.current() +
                          " found. Change your JAVA_HOME environment variable.";
        throw new IllegalStateException(message);
    }
}

compileJava.dependsOn checkJavaVersion
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting... Do you happen to know by any chance (otherwise I'll search it) whether it is possible to use JavaVersion instances as arguments to *Compatibility?

Answer (score 22):

Answer to self, and thanks to [@JBNizet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28065582/1093528) for providing the initial solution...

The solution is indeed to use [`JavaVersion`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/JavaVersion.html), and it happens that both `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` accept a `JavaVersion` as an argument...

Therefore the build file has become this:

```
def javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7;
sourceCompatibility = javaVersion;
targetCompatibility = javaVersion; // defaults to sourceCompatibility
```

And then the task:

```
task enforceVersion << {
    def foundVersion = JavaVersion.current();
    if (foundVersion != javaVersion) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("Wrong Java version; required is "
            + javaVersion + ", but found " + foundVersion);
}

compileJava.dependsOn(enforceVersion);
```

And it works:

```
$ ./gradlew clean compileJava
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:enforceVersion FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/fge/src/perso/grappa-tracer-backport/build.gradle' line: 55

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':enforceVersion'.
> Wrong Java version; required is 1.7, but found 1.8
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! Very helpful.. In my case however, I implemented this with a check to see `if (foundVersion.isJava7Compatible()) { ... }`. Just wanted to share because I thought it was nifty. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the version to be checked for all tasks, you can add an assertion in `build.gradle` to enforce it:

```java
assert JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible(): "Java 9 or newer is required"
```

With Gradle 5.4.1, the failure looks like this:

```
$ ./gradlew --quiet build
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/codehearts/build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Codehearts'.
> Java 9 or newer is required. Expression: org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current().isJava9Compatible()

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
```

You can also check exact versions if needed:

```java
assert JavaVersion.current().isJava9(): "Java 9 is required"
```